# JSON deserialise doesn't give the full string

Tags: apex, json, rest, deserialize

When deserializing a JSON string to `List<Object>` using `JSON.deserializeUntyped( resParams )` the list received is incomplete:

```
{Address=null, BillingAddress=2509, CompanyId=632, County=null, Fax=null, Id=2509, PostCode=null, ShortName=Test Site Ignore, SiteName=Test Site Ignore, Telephone=null, ...}
```

As you can see we get 10 elements and an ellipsis indicating missing elements. Is there a way to get all (12 )elements with deserialize()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't JSON.deserialize, it's Object.toString. Basically, when you debug a non-String, non-null item, System.debug calls Object.toString, which has the behavior of truncating big objects so they don't take up a ton of log space. There's no convenient way to debug the entire object. However, if you use [checkpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm), you can open the checkpoint to observe the object's entire state by way of the checkpoint GUI, or you can convert your object back to a String and debug that via `JSON.serialize(JSON.deserializeUntyped(resParams))`.

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt answer, is there a way to use those missing elements that are in an ellipsis? Unfortunately, I can't pass them into say a SF field. E.g. Town = 'London' is hidden in the ellipsis and I cannot pass it into the SF field. Is there any other way to retrieve all the fields?

Comment: @Baraban Either re-serialize them, or you could process the results via something like `Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resParams); for(String key: values.keys()) { /* do something with values.get(key) */ }`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Basically, I serialized it and broken it into a map<String,Object> and got all the values in the end. All as you suggested!